# Cannot work manually exit from full screen after documentElement.requestFullscreen();

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

I have got Twith player to my site. I have also *'TheatreMode'*.When i turn on *TheatreMode* , i use `documentElement.requestFullscreen()`, which is not opened into full screen mode.RatheriIt opens to a specific part of the screen. After that i have to click manually for full screen.But i cannot exit form full screen manually.

code to open full screen

```
  openStreamTheatreMode(): void {

if (!(<any>document).fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
  !(<any>document).mozFullScreenElement && !(<any>document).webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
  if ((<any>document).documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
    (<any>document).documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else if ((<any>document).documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    (<any>document).documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if ((<any>document).documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    (<any>document).documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
} else {
  this.typeStream.next('big');
}
```

}

[TheatreMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpQ0n.jpg)

Comment: please elaborate on your question... And if possible provide some code

Comment: i added some code

Comment: @Denis does the api from player support the change to small screen?

Comment: I did not check it. I use Twith player

Comment: Maybe you can trigger the keyDown() event with keycode for ESC.

Comment: if i use esc i exit from TheatreMode.I do not need it

Comment: Then ask the developer of this player.